# Get the Y coordinate of a view from bottom

Tags: swift, uiview, position, coordinates, frame

I'm trying to get the Y coordinate of my view form the bottom,

what i mean by that is that when i get the Y coordinate, the number is counted from top, and i want to be able to count it from bottom, is there a way or do i have to do a little math?

i've searched google and stackoverflow but didn't get the exact answer so i'm asking it myself

also i'm trying to get the y coordinate from the whole window and not the superview, i'm doing this because i want to be able to know if i need to add space to my scrollview for keyboard or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the "math". There is no other way.

For the super view:

```
view.superView!.frame.height - view.frame.y
```

For the screen:

Use the screen size and subtract your view's y

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - view.frame.y
```

Comment: ok i didn't wanted to do the math but ok :) but how do i get the y coordinate from whole screen and not the superview

Comment: Updated the answer